# avoid multiple views from same user using cookies

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, count, view

```
$old_views = $row['views'];
$new_views = $old_views + 1;
$sql = "UPDATE posts SET views='".$new_views."' WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND      
id='".$id."' LIMIT 1"; 
$res = mysql_query($sql);
```

Whenever I refresh the page $row['views']; continues adding.
Maybe track IP of the user? From what I understand cookies is the best way. tips would be very helpful...

Answer (score 0):

You can set a cookie or you can track the ip: When a user clicks the page, save the ip and the time of access. If a specific time interval has not passed(Say 24 Hours), do not add the counter, otherwise update the time and add the counter.

Comment: ??   <?php
if (!isset($_COOKIE['visits'])) $_COOKIE['visits'] = 0;
$visits = $_COOKIE['visits'] + 1;
setcookie('visits',$visits,time()+3600*24*365);
 
if ($visits > 1) {
  echo("Visit Number:  $visits.");
}

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cookie method, make sure all the DB queries are made before any HTML is set.

```
<?php

if(!isset($_COOKIE['visited'])){
 $old_views = $row['views'];
 $new_views = $old_views + 1;
 $sql = "UPDATE posts SET views='".$new_views."' WHERE category_id='".$cid."' AND id='".$id."' LIMIT 1"; 
 $res = mysql_query($sql); 
 setcookie ("visited", "true", time() + 60*60*24*7*365);
?>
```

Note that the cookie expiration time is configured to last 1 year from initial visit.

Comment: Note that this isn't so great if you vaguely care about your data